# What are the ticks for when advancing skills?

Tags: skills, character-advancement, troika

In Troika! the numinous edition in chapter 11 *Getting Better* the rules suggest a tick next to the advanced skill on every successful skill roll (roll under) on the character sheet. After rolling for advancement of 3 skills (roll over) the rules state that all ticks have to be removed from the character sheets.

But what are ticks used for? How is the count of ticks relevant?

**Update**: Here is the page from the book.

[image: Rules from the book]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Troika Numinous Edition pg 50 of my pdf copy

> 11. Getting Better Life is learning and you cannot experience it without growing in some way. Your characters will bend and change in
>     response to their environment. When you successfully use a Skill you
>     stand to learn from it. Put a tick next to it on your character sheet.
>     Luck, Skill, and Stamina never change.

You succeed, mark it down next to the advanced skill.

> 11.1 How to Advance The next time you have a chance to rest and reflect on your journey you may check to see what you have learned. If
> you roll 2d6 over your current Skill Total you may increase it by 1.
> You may Test a maximum of 3 Skills in one rest regardless of success
> or failure. When you have finished rolling remove all ticks from your
> sheet.

When you can rest, test up to 3 of your advanced skills marked for advance, delete all tick marks.

There is the [Troika SRD](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1haUfSVekt2gNab3V2CrL1Pg_sZ-ZlskphwXmSnGT9aw/edit?usp=sharing) which has identical text and does get occasionally for minor edits.

Comment: The new wording is a bit unclear. The old one posted by @Anagkai clearly says to to roll for every tick. Was it changed to have just one tick for a skill once used successfully and then just test three times?

Comment: I don't know? I didn't write the rules. You could ask on their discord.

Answer (score 4):

## Ticks are used to improve skills

> For each tick, roll 2d6, aiming to get more than the current Skill Total to improve it by one.

(p. 24, chapter 11.1, *How to advance*)

Either you didn't find this in the numinous edition core book or it was forgotten in that book. It would seem odd that the ticks were kept but their use removed.

I don't know the numinous edition, but this information from the numinous edition kickstarter suggests that the rules system was not changed:

> There are over 40 pieces of new art going into the new edition, alongside a completely new editing sweep, a new introduction, a new layout, rewritten entries encompassing accumulated errata, and potentially new enemies and a short introductory adventure if things go well.

Comment: That sentence is missing! See picture https://rollenspiel.social/system/media_attachments/files/000/013/319/original/1415cd6ea98b15aa.png